# Why did Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0 reported "too many requests" error when writing data?

Tags: session, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I replaced the "lib" profile of Version 1.1.0 and write data in Apache IoTDB, an error was reported: "StatementExecutionException Create breakpoint: 606: Reject write because there are too many requests need to process". I tried to change the configuration, but it didn't work. I didn’t have this problem before. I also set "sessionPool.close()" when writing data, so it seems that this error is not because I forgot to close the sessions. Anyone know why this error orrurs and how to solve the problem?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please